# What does "contrôles radars fréquents" mean?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, transports

I was just playing Euro Truck Simulator 2 and saw this traffic sign in France. I'm not sure what it means.

[image]

Comment: Typo : it's _controleS radarS fréquentS_ and not _controles radar fréquents_. See http://www.securite-routiere.gouv.fr/medias-outils/espace-presse/publications-presse/un-nouveau-panneau-pour-signaler-les-zones-controles-radars-frequents-il-est-place-1-a-2-kilometres-avant-le-premier-radar-au-lieu-des-400-metres-actuels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a sign telling drivers that the police are checking your speed by radar.

Comment: This usually stand for mobile speed checking (not at the same place). It's a different sign for static radar

Comment: @grunk It actually signal static radars, replacing the previous sign that was installed closer to then. Mobile radars are rarely signaled.